# Word for ulterior motive

Tags: single-word-requests

Whats a word for making amends for a wrongdoing but with ulterior motives, ie not altruistically. Does anyone know of a word

Comment: Please describe the situation in more detail. "Making amends" to what, for example? What sort of "amends"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be referring to [self-interested](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Self-interested) excuses:

> related to selfish or excessive regard for one's personal advantage or interest.

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a word that means "making amends for a wrongdoing but with ulterior motives, i.e. not altruistically," but if someone was making such a move, I would say it is a "gimmick." Overall, it means a clever maneuver that works to one's advantage.

Gimmick - 1. an important feature that is not immediately apparent

1. an ingenious and usually new scheme or angle
2. a trick or device used to attract business or attention.

Also consider:
Blind - Something put forward for the purpose of misleading or something designed to conceal one’s real intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but either of the phrases **disingenuous repentance** or **disingenuous remorse** might fit.

According to *Collins American Dictionary*, **[disingenuous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/disingenuous)** means

> not straightforward; not candid or frank; insincere

From the same source, **[repentance](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/repentance)** means

> a repenting or being penitent; feeling of sorrow, etc., esp. for wrongdoing; compunction; contrition; remorse

And again from *Collins*, **[remorse](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/remorse)** means

> a deep, torturing sense of guilt felt over a wrong that one has done; self-reproach